# Remove space above `strip` environment in twocolumn article

Tags: formatting, two-column, cuted

I'm writing a `twocolumn` article and want to include a title that spans both columns:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cuted}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{strip}
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black]
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\centering\Large\textbf{Title of my report}
\end{minipage}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{strip}

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-2]

\section{Method}
\lipsum[1-9]

\end{document}
```

I use [`cuted`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cuted)'s `strip` environment to get:

[image]

How do I remove the space above the red box? The article's margins are 2cm and this space is quite noticeable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\setlength{\stripsep}{0pt}` eliminates spaces around the `strip` environment.

The spaces around the `tcolorbox` can be specified with the `before` and `after` options.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[margin=2cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cuted}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\stripsep}{0pt} % default value: 15pt plus 2pt minus 2pt

\begin{document}

\begin{strip}
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,before={},after={\vspace{15pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}}]
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\centering\Large\textbf{Title of my report}
\end{minipage}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{strip}

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-2]

\section{Method}
\lipsum[1-9]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

At the top of the page, you don't need strip.  The optional argument of `\twocolumn` will do.  (The extra brace is to hide the `\tcolorbox` optional arguments from the parser.)

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cuted}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\twocolumn[{\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black]
\centering\Large\textbf{Title of my report}
\end{tcolorbox}}]

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-2]

\section{Method}
\lipsum[1-9]

\end{document}
```